# /bin/sh: npx: command not found on linux when trying to install using maven

Tags: node.js, linux, maven, devops, npx

I am trying to install the node and npm using maven frontend plugin during build.

pom.xml Configuration as below

```
    <properties>
        <nodejs.version>v14.15.1</nodejs.version>
        <npm.version>6.14.8</npm.version>
        <npmRepoUrl> URL </npmRepoUrl>
        <nodeRepoUrl> URL </nodeRepoUrl>
    </properties>
    

 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>


                <configuration>
                    <nodeDownloadRoot>${nodeRepoUrl}</nodeDownloadRoot>
                    <npmDownloadRoot>${nodeRepoUrl}</npmDownloadRoot>
                    <nodeVersion>${nodejs.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/utilities</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install test</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

Using above configuration node and NPM got installed successfully but still gives error that npx command not found for further operations

```
[INFO] Installing node version v14.15.1
[INFO] Downloading <NODE URL >
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
[INFO] Unpacking 
[INFO] Copying node binary from 
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] Installing npm version 6.14.8
[INFO] Downloading <NPM URL >
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
[INFO] Unpacking 
[INFO] Installed npm locally.
```

Am I missing any configuration can someone please help ?